# Field extraction using lambda from a database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I have a problem when trying to join multiple tables in a database. In fact, I am not quite sure which primary key should I use when creating the connection. So, let's say I have three tables each with its own private key named TownID, HotelID and RoomID. The connection is made through foreign keys in the table Hotel. So my question is how with a given townID can extract information about certain hotel room ?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: edited the mistake with the foreign key

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please post the schema of these tables. Side note: there isn't any concept called secondary keys in any RDBMS, at least as far as I am aware of. There is the concept of the primary key and the concept of the foreign key. A foreign key is associated with the primary key of another table's primary key. Thanks

Comment: Please confirm if these are the correct relationships between your entities. A Town has 0 or more Hotels and an Hotel has 1 or many Rooms. Then, how are named the database tables that contain the elements of these relationships?. Towns, Hotels. Rooms? Finally how are named the fields that keep the relationships? Hotels has a TownID field and Rooms has an HotelID field?

Comment: The table Rooms has two fields number and primary key which plays the role of a foreign key in table hotels. The table Hotels has three fields. The first is name, the second is its primary key and the third is the foreign key of rooms. The third table, which is named Towns, has primary key, name and foreign key which is the primary of the table hotels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table Town
-----------
TownId (PK)

TownName

Table Hotel
------------
HotelId (PK)

HotelAddress

HotelName

HotelTownId (FK)

HotelRoomId (FK)

Table Room
------------
RoomId (PK)

RoomNumber
```

**Provided that** the above is the schema of these tables, then you need something like this:

```
var result = (from h in db.Hotel
             join t in db.Town
             on h.HotelTownId equals t.TownId
             join r in db.Room
             on h.HotelRoomId equals r.RoomId
             where t.TownId == townId
             select r.RoomNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

You could write the above query using lambdas. However in this form is more readable.

Comment: Well, thank you for your response. It worked by adding simple .FirstOrDefault expression at the end of your code. By the way, you have a misspelling at the where clause.